# Blue tag badge message can get misaligned on small screens/windows

Tags: bug, tags, design, information-display

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/350199/revisions) it says that the post was reopened by a bunch of community members, including [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard-wearing-mask). And right next to that user's username is the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag with a yellow circle in it.

Hovering over the [feature](/questions/tagged/feature) portion of that word makes that blue message about it pop up, yet it is misaligned.

[image: misalign]

When I hover my mouse over the *[request](/questions/tagged/request)* portion of the tag however, the same message does appear, but it flashes since the message is covering up that part of the tag. Unfortunately I do not have time to make a gif of it.

However, I think that's because I use chrome in a <sub><sup>*smaller*</sup></sub> window, because when I open the window in full it is no problem.

[image: ok]

It might be a meaningless bug to fix, but if someone browses here on a device with a small screen he is likely to encounter the same problem too.

Maybe the message should be programmed to shift itself to the right/left a bit if the screen appears to be too small or something. I made a mock-up of what it might look like, I apologize for the bad photo editing.

**Before:**

[image: ok]

**After:**

[image: evenbetter]

Obviously, the current solution is to just use a full window. But it still might be worth looking into.

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox.

Comment: @Mark I can reproduce on Chrome as well as Microsoft Edge.